# Database not closed

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-asynctask

I looked at other questions regarding this problem and tried their solutions, but it did not help me unfortunately.

The problem is not of critical nature, meaning my program does not crash, it continues running, but anyway I would like not to have errors if possible.

I am using **AsyncTask** class to create some objects and load them up into an array. Database I use is a file obtained from the net, therefore I have no DBhelper class. I open the DB inside of doInBackround of AsyncTask. Inside it I have try-catch where I do all my db related work.

At first I had variables for *db* and *cursors* inside of the try statement and also I had closure of *db* and *cursors* in it at the end. I found one link saying try-catch-final should be used, so I did that, I moved variable declaration outsite of try-catch-final statement and managed closing of *db* and *cursor* variables in the *final* part, but still it does not help, errors are still here.

Here are some errors, I won't C/P all of them:

> 01-25 17:22:45.142: E/Database(333): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/stet.cityapp/app_databases/baza.db
>
> 01-25 17:22:45.142: E/Database(333): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
>
> 01-25 17:22:45.142: E/Database(333):   at stetocina.cityapp.SplashScreen$LoadDB.doInBackground(SplashScreen.java:1)
>
> 01-25 17:22:45.142: E/Database(333):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
>
> 01-25 17:22:45.142: E/Database(333):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)

Outline of the code:

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
SQLiteDatabase db = null;
Cursor poisCursor = null, tmpCursor = null;
String whereString;
try {               
    String DBpath = getDir("databases", 0).getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "baza.db";
    if (SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DBpath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY) == null) return false;
    db =  SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DBpath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
    
    ...
    
    result = true;
} catch (Exception e) {
    result = false;
    return result;
} finally {
    if (!poisCursor.isClosed() || poisCursor != null) {
        poisCursor.deactivate();
        poisCursor.close();
        poisCursor = null;
    }
    if (!db.isOpen() || db != null) {
        db.close();
        db = null;
    }
}
return result;
```

}

Could there be some problem that I am doing it in an AsyncTask? In the **onPostExecute** methond of AsyncTaks, if everything went well and result is true, I open a new Activity, and while debugging I noticed that the error is displayed only when new activity is displayed and not immediatelly after exit from doInBackground.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't the database being opened twice?

1. inside the 'if' condition (if (SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DBpath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY) == null) return false;)
2. in the next line (db =  SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DBpath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);)

and you are closing only the second one(db).

Answer (score 0):

Look closely :) This

```
if (!db.isOpen() || db != null) {
    db.close();
    db = null;
}
```

will try to close the db only if it is **not open**.
Also, I think there's something wrong with the

```
|| x != null
```

part of both clauses.

In Java, the "double" logical operators are *conditional*. For || that means if the first argument is **true** then the second argument will not be evaluated at all, since logical OR will already be true no matter what. If it's not - then your link is checked for null. So, what you're doing is, you check whether cursor is closed. And if it **is** closed, you check the link for null - which obviously will be true given you succeeded calling any method on it, so no use of the second check.

I think the right clauses will be

```
if ( poisCursor != null && !poisCursor.isClosed()) // prevent NPE when calling .isClosed() in case poisCursor is null
```

and

```
if (db != null && db.isOpen()) // same thing + note the absence of negation
```

(You can read more on conditional operators in detail here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

**Edit:** @firebolt7 is right, you're losing reference to the object you get when calling open() in if clause.

Comment: Although the `!db.isOpen()` looks wrong as you say, the second part of the check, `db != null`, will succeed, so this is not the cause of the error.

Comment: Hmm, yes, you're right. So the attempt to close db should take place anyway. Then firebolt7 must be right - you're losing link to one of db instances, I've missed that part :)

Comment: Thanks for looking into it, but error was as firebolt7 suggested. This if clause opened the db, I had it from before, to test if db exists and I never thought of closing it since I thought android will do it by itself as I have not plased this connection into a variable. My mistake. Also the negation of db.isOpen, you are right.