# SQLite database not closing

Tags: c#, sqlite

I keep on getting exceptions on another form which adds to the sqlite database saying that database is locked, but when i try and put the data into a new database, it works. The only conlusion I can draw is that the database isnt closing properly maintaining its lock. Can anyone help?

```
SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=./LibraryDB.db;Version=3;");
        SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd;
        SQLiteDataReader sqlite_datareader;
        sqlite_conn.Open();
        sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Books";
        sqlite_cmd.CommandText = query;
        sqlite_datareader = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader();
        //Initialise table
        listBooks.View = View.Details;
        listBooks.GridLines = true;
        listBooks.FullRowSelect = true;
        listBooks.Columns.Add("ID", 100);
        listBooks.Columns.Add("ISBN", 100);
        listBooks.Columns.Add("Title", 100);
        listBooks.Columns.Add("Author", 100);
        listBooks.Columns.Add("Year", 100);
        listBooks.Columns.Add("Edition", 100);
        listBooks.Columns.Add("TagID", 150);
        DataTable booksDataTable = new DataTable();
        SQLiteDataAdapter booksDataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(query, sqlite_conn);
        DataSet booksDataSet = new DataSet();
        booksDataAdapter.Fill(booksDataSet);
        foreach (DataRow row in booksDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            ListViewItem listitem = new ListViewItem(row[0].ToString());
            for (int i = 1; i < booksDataSet.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                listitem.SubItems.Add(row[i].ToString());
            }
            listBooks.Items.Add(listitem);
        }
        sqlite_conn.Close();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Database not closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006485/database-not-closed)

Comment: Create, use and dispose of your connections as you need them.  There are handy `using` statements for just such things

Comment: Try setting to null : sqlite_conn = null;

Comment: @jdweng no dice unfortunately

Comment: What about Dispose()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at

- [Using objects that implement IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects)

You use a lot of objects whose classes implement `IDisposable` (for example, `SQLiteConnection`, `SQLiteCommand`,  `SQLiteDataReader`), but you don't dispose them correctly. Thus, unmanaged resources are not released and stuff that should not be locked stays locked.

The solution: *Every single time* you create an object whose class implements `IDisposable`, you either

- use it with a `using` statement, e.g.,

  ```
  using (var sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=./LibraryDB.db;Version=3;"))
  {
      ...
  }
  ```
- or manually ensure that it is always disposed (usually involving a `try-finally` block).

Details on how to use these patterns can be found in the link above.

Comment: I put SQLiteConnection, SQLiteCommand and SQLiteDataReader in using statements and it all works, thank you